# How can I run tcpdump from a Python script without AppArmor complaining?

Tags: python, tcpdump, apparmor

For inconvenient reasons going beyond the scope of this question, I have to run `tcpdump` from within a Python script. I currently just call `subprocess.Popen(['tcpdump', ...)` and everything works just fine. However, when I use tools like pyInstaller to package the script into an executable, and run it (as root), I get the following error:

```
tcpdump: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.0.9.8: "failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied"
```

As I found out, this is AppArmor whining. Now, I can easily replace my call to tcpdump with the following:

```
subprocess.call(['aa-complain', '/usr/sbin/tcpdump'])
pcap = subprocess.Popen(['tcpdump', ...)
subprocess.call(['aa-enforce', '/usr/sbin/tcpdump'])
```

Now it prints two info lines (about changing into complain/enforce mode), and runs tcpdump without further complaints.

The people who will run this script will run it as root when they want to do packet captures, so I don't see how this is a security problem. At the same time, the above seems hackish to me. So to the AppArmor experts among you: is this the canonical way to deal with it?

PS. I'm also thankful for links to a good, quick introduction to AppArmor in general, since this is the first time I'm encountering this.

Answer (score 1):

Well this should be a start, if you haven't already browsed it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor